# Git commands to move from TFVC to TFS Git

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc, git-tf

Just tried to do the following using the paths relative to my setup,

```
git tf clone https://nakedalm.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection $/TfsExtensions/TfPlugable c:\temp\TfPlugable
cd C:\Users\MrHinsh\Source\Repos\TfPlugable
git remote add tfplugable-tfvc-branch c:\temp\TfPlugable
git pull tfplugable-tfvc-branch master --deep
git checkin
```

when I use the tag --deep, it says "error: unknown option 'deep'

Method applied using the [following blog post](http://nakedalm.com/migrating-source-code-with-history-to-tfs-2012-with-git-tf/).

Comment: `--deep` is default for pull... I suspect it should have been `git tf clone --deep`, see: https://gittf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Clone&referringTitle=Home

Comment: So, are you suggesting the steps of the process are incorrect? If applying what's in that link, then the '--deep' should've been used on the first step. But, wouldn't this produce different results? Need to know before doing the clone again since it isn't exactly a quick process.

Comment: Yes, I very much suspect that the sequence should be just `git clone --deep https://nakedalm.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection $/TfsExtensions/TfPlugable c:\temp\TfPlugable` and that should be enough. I suspect that `git tf` was updated since 2012.

Comment: Perhaps you will have more luck with a still active software  [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md)

Comment: @jessehouwing I'm in the process of running your suggestion now.

Comment: @jessehouwing that seems to work, but for the life of me, i can't figure out how to get this mess checked in.

Comment: To a Git Repository on TFS? `Git remote add TFS-Git http://uri-to-your-remote-git-repo` followed by `git push master TFS-Git/master --all` should do the trick...

Comment: All seems to be working well...Going to try using Chocolatey instead.